# Solving $8$ variables with $2$ equations

Tags: summation, systems-of-equations

Lets say we have $8$ variables (each variable can have a value from $1$ to $10$ only) with $2$ equations -

$A + B + C + D + E + F + G + H = {\text{SUM}}\\
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H = {\text{DIFF}}$

What is the fastest algorithm which can find out the values of variables, given the sum and difference values.

For example,

$A = 8\\
B = 7\\
C = 10\\
D = 5\\
E = 10\\
F = 3\\
G = 9\\
H = 1$

$A + B + C + D + E + F + G + H = 53\\
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H = -37$

So, given the values $53$ and $-37,$ how can we find values of all $8$ variables?

There is a brute force approach by substituting each variable with values from $1$ to $10$ and checking the sum and difference, but it will take a long time.

How can we achieve it in a faster way?

Thanks.

Comment: You need 8 equations for 8 variables. With the 2 we currently have, we can only calculate A.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you realize there could be solutions other than the one you gave; for example, $A=8, B=9, C=D=E=F=G=H=6$?

Comment: Must the variables be integers?  (You didn't say.)

Comment: Yes it must be integers.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the two equations, we see $A = \frac{\{SUM\}+\{DIFF\}}{2}$.  Consequently, if two does not divide $\{SUM\}+\{DIFF\}$, there is no solution.  Also, we require $2 \leq \{SUM\}+\{DIFF\} \leq 20$, or no solution is possible.

Subtracting the second equation from the first, $B +C +D+E+F+G+H= \frac{\{SUM\}-\{DIFF\}}{2}$.  The requirement that two divides $\{SUM\}+\{DIFF\}$ automatically causes two to divide $\{SUM\}-\{DIFF\}$, so we do not have a new condition to check for the existence of a solution.  However, we must have $14 \leq \{SUM\}-\{DIFF\} \leq 140$, or no solution is possible.

Assuming a solution exists, for each  [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $\frac{\{SUM\}-\{DIFF\}}{2}$ into seven parts of size in $[1,10]$, emit a solution.  There can be a lot of these.  When $\frac{\{SUM\}-\{DIFF\}}{2} = 39$, there are $512\,365$ solutions.  (Found using the generating function $(x+x^2+\cdots+x^{10})^7$.)

Note that since $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$, $G$, and $H$ are all at least $1$, we might as well generate compositions of $\frac{\{SUM\}-\{DIFF\}}{2} - 7$ having seven parts of size in $[0,9]$, then add $1$ to each part to get the value to assign to its variable.

Optimal time generation of compositions is still an area of ongoing research.  ([example](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.2331.pdf))  Since the ranges of these variables are so narrow, I would probably use the non-tricky "six nested for loops" method.

```
(* do the various checks described above to see if there are any solutions before proceeding *)
A := ({SUM}+{DIFF})/2
tot := ({SUM}-{DIFF})/2
for B = max(1,tot-6*10) to min(10,tot)
  for C = max(1,tot-B-5*10) to min(10, tot-B)
    for D = max(1,tot-B-C-4*10) to min(10, tot-B-C)
      for E = max(1,tot-B-C-D-3*10) to min(10, tot-B-C-D)
        for F = max(1,tot-B-C-D-E-2*10) to min(10, tot-B-C-D-E)
          for G = max(1,tot-B-C-D-E-F-10) to min(10, tot-B-C-D-E-F)
            H = tot-B-C-D-E-F-G
            if 1 <= H <= 10
              emit the solution (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)
```

The principle effect of the `max(1,tot-...)` lower bounds is to force variables to start at the least value that will reach `tot` assuming all subsequent variables are maxed out.

(It's late/early here and I haven't tested this code, so it likely contains typos and bugs.  Corrections in comments are welcome.)

Comment: Only integers are allowed, so we probably cannot divide each result by 2. Also, for more than 1 solution, we need to find all possible solutions.

Comment: @DaveHenry : If $\{SUM\} + \{DIFF\}$ is not divisible by $2$, there is no solution.  $A$ is *always* $\frac{\{SUM\} + \{DIFF\}}{2}$.  (Add your two equations together to see this.)